# How to plot data from 2 different tables in one plot in Access?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have 2 tables in Access, that are created with 2 different queries.
I would like to put 2 tables data in 1 plot, not in 2 separate plots instead.
the table are extracted with 2 following separate queries:

```
SELECT count(*) AS [Count], History.[activationDate]
FROM History
WHERE History.activationDate is not null
GROUP BY History.[activationDate];

SELECT count(*) AS [Count], History.[deactivationDate]
FROM History
WHERE History.deactivationDate is not null and deactivationDate < lastSeenDate
GROUP BY History.[deactivationDate];
```

Comment: And you will sort both by activationDate and deactivationDate? How?

Comment: I just count number of activation for the day x and number of disactivation for day x, then for each day i have 2 columns

Answer (score 0):

Then it could be:

```
SELECT 
    Sum(Abs(History.activationDate is not null)) AS [ActiveCount],
    Sum(Abs(History.deactivationDate is not null)) AS [DeactiveCount],
    [SearchDateX] As SearchDate
FROM 
    History
WHERE
    (History.deactivationDate + History.deactivationDate Is Not Null)
    And
    (History.deactivationDate = [SearchDateX] 
        OR
    History.deactivationDate = [SearchDateX])
```

Or for all days:

```
SELECT 
    History.activationDate,
    History.deactivationDate,
    Sum(Abs(History.activationDate is not null)) AS [ActiveCount],
    Sum(Abs(History.deactivationDate is not null)) AS [DeactiveCount],
FROM 
    History
GROUP BY
    History.activationDate,
    History.deactivationDate
HAVING
    (History.activationDate Is Not Null)
        OR
    (History.deactivationDate Is Not Null
    And
    History.deactivationDate < lastSeenDate)
```

Comment: Unfortunately Access returns a Syntaxis error (missing operator)

Comment: Hmm i think it messes "=" in the last row. Actually i would like that access does count for each date automatically, that i do not have to enter it from keyboard. And i do not know if a query above considers also following condition: History.deactivationDate is not null and deactivationDate < lastSeenDate